# Smarty counter start with zero on single digits

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I would like to know whether it is possible to add a zero before single digits on smarty.

Normaly in PHP when i add below code it will count from 1-9 with a zero (Ex: 01, 02, 03 so on)

```
printf("%02d", $i++);
```

But with im not sure how to apply this. Smarty `{counter}` will simply count 1, 2, 3 etc.

Any advice is highly appropriated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8674831/1415724 --- `{$number++}` and answers in that post, also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4600175/1415724 maybe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you increment an assigned variable in smarty without displaying it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674831/how-do-you-increment-an-assigned-variable-in-smarty-without-displaying-it)

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Smarty but this looks like something you are looking for

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.string.format.tpl

Answer (score 0):

In Smarty, you can use following syntax: `{$index|string_format:"%02d"}`

Sample with a section loop:

```
{section name="myloop" loop="10" step="1"}
  {$index = $smarty.section.myloop.index+1}
  {$index|string_format:"%02d"}
{/section}
```

Sample with a for loop:

```
{for $index=1 to 10}
  {$index|string_format:"%02d"}
{/for}
```

Sample with a foreach loop:

```
{$array = ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']}
{foreach $array as $index => $el}
  {$index = $index+1}
  {$index|string_format:"%02d"}
{/foreach}
```

All of this samples will output:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
```